# Annotating an Image in AS3 with a Rectangle and Save Result

Tags: image, actionscript-3, bitmap, rectangles

I am currently looking at a face detection example found in a zip file here:

[Marilena_mod10.zip](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php)

The example loads an image and then highlights the face with a black rectangle.
I would like to save the resulting image, in other words, annotate the image with a square and nothing else (just the image and square, not the entire stage).

So far I can save the image by processing it as bitmap data and resaving it, but I cannot save the 'square'. I've tried copying the line that draws the square and drawing it to another bitmap object, tried drawing it on a sprite, and I've tried using a matrix figuring it was being drawn out of bounds. No luck.

Below is the original code followed by my futile attempts (I realize it saves a blank white image, I was trying to see if I could just draw a square):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetector;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorOptions;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorEvent;

    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class FaceDetector extends Sprite{
        private var debug :Boolean = true;

        private var detector    :ObjectDetector;
        private var options     :ObjectDetectorOptions;
        private var faceImage   :Loader;
        private var bmpTarget   :Bitmap;

        private var view :Sprite;
        private var faceRectContainer :Sprite;
        private var tf :TextField;

        private var lastTimer:int = 0;

        public function FaceDetector() {
            initUI();
            initDetector();
            faceImage.load( new URLRequest("013.jpg") );
        }

        private function initUI():void{
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            view = new Sprite;
            addChild(view);

            faceImage = new Loader;
            faceImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, function(e :Event) :void {
                startDetection();
            });
            view.addChild( faceImage );

            faceRectContainer = new Sprite;
            view.addChild( faceRectContainer );

            tf = new TextField;
            tf.x = 256;
            tf.width  = 600;
            tf.height = 300;
            tf.textColor = 0x000000;
            tf.multiline = true;
            view.addChild( tf );
        }

        private function initDetector():void{
            detector = new ObjectDetector;
            detector.options = getDetectorOptions();
            detector.addEventListener(ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE,function( e :ObjectDetectorEvent ):void{
                logger("[ObjectDetectorEvent.COMPLETE]");
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
                detector.removeEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE, arguments.callee );

                if( e.rects ){
                    var g :Graphics = faceRectContainer.graphics;
                    g.clear();
                    g.lineStyle( 2 );   // black 2pix
                    e.rects.forEach( function( r :Rectangle, idx :int, arr :Array ) :void {
                        g.drawRect( r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height );
                    });
                }
            });

            detector.addEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_START, function(e :ObjectDetectorEvent) :void {
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
            });

        }

        private function startDetection():void{
            logger("[startDetection]");

            bmpTarget = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) )
            bmpTarget.bitmapData.draw( faceImage );
            detector.detect( bmpTarget.bitmapData );
        }

        private function getDetectorOptions() :ObjectDetectorOptions {
            options = new ObjectDetectorOptions();
            options.min_size  = 50;
            return options;
        }

        private function logger(... args):void{
            if(!debug){ return; }
            trace( args, getTimer(),  getTimer() - lastTimer);
            lastTimer = getTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

My code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.*;//Rectangle;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetector;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorOptions;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorEvent;
    import com.adobe.images.*;

    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    ////
    import flash.filesystem.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    ////

    public class FaceDetector extends Sprite{
        private var debug :Boolean = true;

        private var detector    :ObjectDetector;
        private var options     :ObjectDetectorOptions;
        private var faceImage   :Loader;
        private var bmpTarget   :Bitmap;

        private var view :Sprite;
        private var faceRectContainer :Sprite;
        private var tf :TextField;

        private var lastTimer:int = 0;

        public function FaceDetector() {
            initUI();
            initDetector();
            faceImage.load( new URLRequest("013.jpg") );
        }

        private function initUI():void{
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            view = new Sprite;
            addChild(view);

            faceImage = new Loader;
            faceImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, function(e :Event) :void {
                startDetection();
            });
            view.addChild( faceImage );

            faceRectContainer = new Sprite;
            view.addChild( faceRectContainer );

            tf = new TextField;
            tf.x = 256;
            tf.width  = 600;
            tf.height = 300;
            tf.textColor = 0x000000;
            tf.multiline = true;
            view.addChild( tf );
        }

        private function initDetector():void{
            detector = new ObjectDetector;
            detector.options = getDetectorOptions();
            detector.addEventListener(ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE,function( e :ObjectDetectorEvent ):void{
                logger("[ObjectDetectorEvent.COMPLETE]");
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
                detector.removeEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE, arguments.callee );

                var rt:Sprite    = new Sprite();
                var bmprt:Bitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) );
                var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
                var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();

                if( e.rects ){
                    var g :Graphics = faceRectContainer.graphics;
                    g.clear();
                    g.lineStyle( 2 );   // black 2pix
                    e.rects.forEach( function( r :Rectangle, idx :int, arr :Array ) :void {
                        g.drawRect( r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height );

                        matrix.translate(-r.x, -r.y);
                        rect = r;
                        rt.graphics.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height );
                    });
                }

                var file:File                   = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("testoutput.jpg");
                var fs:FileStream               = new FileStream();
                var byteArray:ByteArray;
                var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder( 90 );


                //rt.graphics.draw(g);

                bmpTarget.bitmapData.draw(rt);
                bmprt.bitmapData.draw(rt, matrix);

                byteArray     = jpgEncoder.encode( bmprt.bitmapData );
                fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(byteArray);
                fs.close();

            });

            detector.addEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_START, function(e :ObjectDetectorEvent) :void {
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
            });

        }

        private function startDetection():void{
            logger("[startDetection]");
            bmpTarget = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) )
            bmpTarget.bitmapData.draw( faceImage );
            detector.detect( bmpTarget.bitmapData );
        }

        private function getDetectorOptions() :ObjectDetectorOptions {
            options = new ObjectDetectorOptions();
            options.min_size  = 50;
            return options;
        }

        private function logger(... args):void{
            if(!debug){ return; }
            trace( args, getTimer(),  getTimer() - lastTimer);
            lastTimer = getTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

TL;DR:

How do you load an image, draw a square on it, and then save the result, assuming you already know how to load and save images?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

Here is the final code for anyone interested:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.*;//Rectangle;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetector;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorOptions;
    import jp.maaash.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectorEvent;
    import com.adobe.images.*;

    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    ////
    import flash.filesystem.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    ////

    public class FaceDetector extends Sprite{
        private var debug :Boolean = true;

        private var detector    :ObjectDetector;
        private var options     :ObjectDetectorOptions;
        private var faceImage   :Loader;
        private var bmpTarget   :Bitmap;

        private var view :Sprite;
        private var faceRectContainer :Sprite;
        private var tf :TextField;

        private var lastTimer:int = 0;

        public function FaceDetector() {
            initUI();
            initDetector();
            faceImage.load( new URLRequest("013.jpg") );
        }

        private function initUI():void{
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            view = new Sprite;
            addChild(view);

            faceImage = new Loader;
            faceImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, function(e :Event) :void {
                startDetection();
            });
            view.addChild( faceImage );

            faceRectContainer = new Sprite;
            view.addChild( faceRectContainer );

            tf = new TextField;
            tf.x = 256;
            tf.width  = 600;
            tf.height = 300;
            tf.textColor = 0x000000;
            tf.multiline = true;
            view.addChild( tf );
        }

        private function initDetector():void{
            detector = new ObjectDetector;
            detector.options = getDetectorOptions();
            detector.addEventListener(ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE,function( e :ObjectDetectorEvent ):void{
                logger("[ObjectDetectorEvent.COMPLETE]");
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
                detector.removeEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_COMPLETE, arguments.callee );

                var bmprt:Bitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) );

                if( e.rects ){
                    var g :Graphics = faceRectContainer.graphics;
                    g.clear();
                    g.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000, 1);    // black 2pix--- parameters(thicknes in pixels, color in hex, alpha (0-1))
                    e.rects.forEach( function( r :Rectangle, idx :int, arr :Array ) :void {
                        g.drawRect( r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height );
                    });
                }

                var file:File                   = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("testoutput.jpg");
                var fs:FileStream               = new FileStream();
                var byteArray:ByteArray;
                var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder( 90 );

                bmprt.bitmapData.draw(faceImage);
                bmprt.bitmapData.draw(faceRectContainer);

                byteArray     = jpgEncoder.encode( bmprt.bitmapData );
                fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(byteArray);
                fs.close();

            });

            detector.addEventListener( ObjectDetectorEvent.DETECTION_START, function(e :ObjectDetectorEvent) :void {
                tf.appendText( "\ntime: "+(new Date)+" "+e.type );
            });

        }

        private function startDetection():void{
            logger("[startDetection]");
            bmpTarget = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) )
            bmpTarget.bitmapData.draw( faceImage );
            detector.detect( bmpTarget.bitmapData );
        }

        private function getDetectorOptions() :ObjectDetectorOptions {
            options = new ObjectDetectorOptions();
            options.min_size  = 50;
            return options;
        }

        private function logger(... args):void{
            if(!debug){ return; }
            trace( args, getTimer(),  getTimer() - lastTimer);
            lastTimer = getTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Vesper for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you load the image as a `Bitmap`, then determine where to draw the rectangle, create a `Shape` and draw the rectangle on its `graphics`, then call `bitmap.bitmapData.draw(shape)` to draw the rectangle over the loaded bitmap, then save the bitmap. In your code, after you've prepared the rectangles, you do something like this:

```
bmprt.bitmapData.copyPixels(faceImage.bitmapData,faceImage.bitmapData.rect,new Point());
bmprt.bitmapData.draw(faceRectContainer);
```

Then save `bmprt` as you do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, did not have time to try this out until last night.

Comment: I get an error for the first of those two lines you wrote. But I changed it to: `    bmprt.bitmapData.draw(faceImage);
    bmprt.bitmapData.draw(faceRectContainer);` And it worked.

Comment: @ErasmoMorales This means your `FaceImage` is not a bitmap. Okay, you did right.